# Used SQL Svr 2008 Config Manager to Set Service Account to Local System: What Did It Change?

Tags: sql-server-2008, security, local-system, configuration-management

Direct shot to foot moment...

While setting-up individual non-admin accts for MSSQLSERVER services, I temporarily set Server service login to Local System account.

I remembered later that:

SQL Server Configuration Manager performs additional configuration such as setting permissions in the Windows Registry so that the new account can read the SQL Server settings.

I want my Local System back . (Actually just restored to its original security profile)

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL SErver 2005/2008 should give those permissions using Windows groups, so if I remember right, all it actually does is switch out the group membership. So when you switch back to your regular service account, all that should be undone. With that said, remember that System has rights as a member of local Administrators group member + additional implicit rights. So nothing you did by switching to System actually gave it more rights than it already could have had.

Comment: That sounds like what I was gathering/hoping from what I've read... Thank you for the reassurance.

Comment: depends on the OS, local system permissions were locked down better in 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if uninstalling SQL server will rest the perms back to what they were. You can however reset the perms to the defautls by applying the default security template:

secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secsetup.inf /db secsetup.sdb /verbose

See [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313222) for details